# SELECT to Block user1 from user2 (Vice Versa)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, profile, blocking

I've stumbled upon an issue with my user to user block feature.

I don't know how to write my `SELECT` to get the right results. When User1 blocks user2 both users can't see each others profiles but when I log in I can see my own account. I'm using a switch to do this.

My `BLOCK` table consists of `ID`, `USER1_ID`, `USER2_ID` and `STATUS`. `0` being 'viewable' and `1` being 'blocked'.

Function.user

```
public function check_block($user1_id,$user2_id){ 
    $check_sql= "SELECT ......"; 
    $check_query = mysql_query($check_sql)or die(mysql_error()); 
    $check_num = mysql_num_rows($check_query); 
    if($check_num>0){ 
        $block = mysql_fetch_array($check_query); 
        return $block['status']; 
    }else{ 
        return $check_num; 
    } 
}
```

SWITCH

```
<? 
    $user1_id=$_SESSION['id'];
    $user2_id=$data['id'];
    $userblock = function_user_core::check_block($user1_id,$user2_id);
    switch($userblock){
        case 1:
            echo'You Are Blocked From Viewing This Users Profile';
            break;
    }
?>
```

Field Blocked In User profile

```
<? if($userblock==1) { ?> 
    THIS USER HAS BLOCKED YOU FROM THEIR ACCOUNT
<? } ?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are asking for an example query.

It looks like you need a query that will test for the existence of a row in the `block` table where the `status` is set to "blocked" (1) for a given pair of users. From the wording of your question, it looks like the order of the user_id values doesn't matter. It doesn't matter (to this query) whether 'foo' blocked 'bar' or 'bar' blocked 'foo', or both.  It looks like your code is going to execute the same exact path in all of those cases. (If I understood your question correctly.)

This query should get that:

```
SELECT b.status
  FROM block b
 WHERE ( b.status = 1 AND b.user1_id = 'foo' AND b.user2_id = 'bar' )
    OR ( b.status = 1 AND b.user1_id = 'bar' AND b.user2_id = 'foo' )
 LIMIT 1
```

NOTE: this query doesn't account for the corner case where user has blocked himself. See below for a query that also handles that condition.

I've used literals 'foo' and 'bar' in my example query, where you would of course substitute your (properly escaped) variables in the SQL text.

For this check query, it only needs to return a row if it finds a row that specifies that a given pair of users is "blocked". Otherwise, the query doesn't need to return any rows. With this query, your code can actually be a little simpler. Using this query, you could simply return the value from mysql_num_rows.

That is, you could replace this block:

```
$check_num = mysql_num_rows($check_query); 
if($check_num>0){ 
    $block = mysql_fetch_array($check_query); 
    return $block['status']; 
}else{ 
    return $check_num; 
}
```

With this:

```
$check_num = mysql_num_rows($check_query); 
return $check_num;
```

---

The query above doesn't account for the (unusual?) corner case, where a user has blocked himself.

If the table contains a row like this:

```
('foo','foo',1)
```

And you pass in values of 'foo' and 'foo' as user_1 and user_2, the query above will return a row. But you specified that a user should always be able to view their own profile.

So, if you want to ignore any rows that specify the condition where a user has "blocked" himself from his own profile, you can add another predicate in your query, to simply disregard any rows where the user_id values match:

```
SELECT 1 AS `status`
  FROM block b
 WHERE b.user1_id <> b.user2_id
   AND b.status = 1
   AND (  ( b.user1_id = 'foo' AND b.user2_id = 'bar' )
       OR ( b.user2_id = 'foo' AND b.user1_id = 'bar' )
       )
 LIMIT 1
```

Also note that if there are conflicting rows in the table, that is, one raw that says the user pair is "blocked" and another row that says the pair is not blocked, the "blocked" status will take precedence.

Note that we don't even really need to return the `status` column, we can return a literal value (with an appropriate alias to provide the result set metadata your code is expecting.)

It doesn't look like you have any problem in your code, though I likely would have coded it a bit differently. The important thing is that it is understandable, and that it works.

---

**UPDATE:**

Sorry it's not working for you.  Here is a SQL Fiddle demonstration of the query I provided.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21120/2

It's most likely that I misunderstood what you were trying to accomplish with your query. What my query achieves is, if

- 'foo' blocks 'bar' or
- 'bar' blocks 'foo' or
- both block each other

then when passed in parameters of `('foo','bar')` or `('bar','foo')` (in either order), the query returns a row with status = 1.

Otherwise, that is, if neither user has 'blocked' the other, the query returns no rows.

It's important in the query that each of the two supplied "user_id" parameters be supplied twice, in the correct positions. (It's possible to rewrite the query so that each of the arguments only need to be supplied once, but that query isn't as easy (for me) to understand.)

Comment: Its still blocking the content on my page and not on the user I've blocked. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. As I've edited your foo with USER1_ID and your bar with USER2_ID..

Comment: Thank you for your time and your honesty 'spencer7593' your skills, knowledge and hospitality is appreciated. I will take your suggestions and advise on board. You deserve the rep you have.

Comment: So if I'm friends with user2 and block them..How would I extend on this to remove the user from my friends on blocking them? Would I do this in blockuser.php at the same time as inserting the block? `if ($_GET['uid']) {
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO block (user1_id, user2_id, status) VALUES('$user1_id','$user2_id', 1)")  or die (mysql_error());
}
if($query){
echo "You've Blocked This User - See Block list in your profileCp to Unblock this user";
}`

Comment: @dave: I expect you have an "unfrienduser" function/routine that handles removing a friend. If your requirement is that a "blocking" a user also remove them as a friend, then your code could just call the function/friend. That's how I would do it.

Answer (score 3):

i believe this is what you are looking for

```
SELECT `STATUS` FROM `BLOCK` WHERE `USER1_ID`=X AND `USER2_ID`=Y;
```

function would be

```
public function check_block($user1_id,$user2_id){ 
    $check_sql= "SELECT `STATUS` FROM `BLOCK` WHERE `USER1_ID`=$user1_id AND `USER2_ID`=$user2_id;"; 
    $check_query = mysql_query($check_sql)or die(mysql_error()); 
    $check_num = mysql_num_rows($check_query); 
    if($check_num>0){ 
        $block = mysql_fetch_assoc($check_query); 
        return (int)$block['status']; 
    }else{ 
        return $check_num; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Its hiding the session content and not the data content. I need it to hide the opposite users content..

Comment: user1 blocks user2 from viewing user1 contents, you want to block user1 from viewing his content?

Comment: When me the session user (user1) blocks any other specific user (user2) my content hides from user2 and user2's content hides from me (user1) but I've just changed 1 to zero where the content hides the given area <? if($userblock==0) { ?> It is now working..But surely it should be 1 to hide..not zero....As the status in the block table is default zero until a user hits block and it sets it to 1.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to the rest of the answers

```
public function check_block($user1_id,$user2_id){ 
    $check_sql= "SELECT * FROM BLOCK WHERE USER1_ID = '$user1_id' AND USER2_ID = '$user2_id'  AND STATUS = 1"; 
    $check_query = mysql_query($check_sql)or die(mysql_error()); 
    $check_num = mysql_num_rows($check_query); 
    return $check_num;
}
```

But I don't think your problem lies how you construct the Query. It lies in `Switch`;
Since you want the user1 to check whether user2 blocked user1 or not, you need to reverse the order of the variable passing into your function.

```
<?php 
    $user1_id=$_SESSION['id'];
    $user2_id=$data['id'];
    $userblock = function_user_core::check_block($user2_id, $user1_id);
    switch($userblock){
        case 1:
            echo'You Are Blocked From Viewing This Users Profile';
            break;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
public function check_block($user1_id,$user2_id) { 
    $check_sql= "SELECT STATUS FROM BLOCK WHERE USER1_ID = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($user1_id) . "' AND USER2_ID = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($user2_id) . "'"; 
    $check_query = mysql_query($check_sql)or die(mysql_error()); 
    $check_num = mysql_num_rows($check_query); 
    if ($check_num>0) { 
        $block = mysql_fetch_array($check_query); 
        return $block['STATUS']; 
    } else { 
        return $check_num; 
    } 
}
```

Enjoy and good luck!

Comment: That is what I had before 'Hope I helped'. But the only thing is..Its still showing the content inside the '$userblock==1'